# Stripe Subscription problems with Laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel-4, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I have been using cashier to create subscriptions for a couple sites but when I tried to implement it again in an new app it's not working. I am getting `Stripe Notice: Undefined property of Laravel\\Cashier\\Customer instance: default_card`. Is there an update to Cashier or a property/code I need to change to make it work again?

I have the BillableTrait attached to the School Model and am trying to subscribe to a subscriptions (in Stripe) using `$school->subscribe($input['school_plan'])->create($input['stripeToken']);`

Comment: I think the issue here is that you're on an API version that doesn't support `default_card` anymore and instead has `default_source`. You'd need a more recent version of Cashier if any. Otherwise you need to force an older API version in the code. This was changed here: https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2015-02-18

Comment: How can you use the old api? Is there something in stripe that lets you generate keys for the old api? I'm using the js I used in other projects and just had new keys generated

Comment: The API version is set automatically when you make your first API call. You could force an API version for all your API calls as explained here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#versioning

Comment: I am trying to figure out what can be changed in Laravel\Cashier (for L4) to make it play nice with the new API. Is it in the JS to generate the return token? I am looking at the Stripe API for using a custom form and not seeing any differences from what i am using.

Comment: Is it possible to use Cashier 3.0 in a L4.2 app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add 'version' => '2014-06-17' to the services.php page for the Stripe info array. It requests the older API and successfully works.